# How can I convert a react component into an image?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple bubble component I created, and I want to convert it into an image so I can use it as a google maps api marker.

I have tried using reactdomrender

```
        const bubbleComponent = <Bubble price={price}/>
        const bubbleHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(bubbleComponent)
        const dataURL = await toPng(bubbleHTML)   
        console.log(dataURL)
        return dataURL;
```

But, the component does not show up as an image on the map.

```
                        const iconDataURL = bubbleDataURL(th.price);
                        return(
                            <MarkerF
                                key={th.id}
                                position={{ lat: th.lat, lng: th.lng}}
                                icon={{
                                    url: bubbleDataURL,
                                    scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(40, 40),
                                }}
                            />  
                        )
```

I do not know what I could be missing. This is the Bubble component.

```
const Bubble = ({price}) => {
  const bubbleStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    border: '1px solid #264068',
    borderRadius: '12px',
    backgroundColor: '#264068',
    color: 'white',
    width: 'fit-content',
    height: '30px',
    padding: '4px',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bubble" style={bubbleStyle}>
        <p>{price}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Bubble
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like a fiddle or codesandbox that we can play around with?